# Solidity: Update staking rewards

Tags: solidity

In our usecase, we have to reduce the staking reward amount after 1 day. For example, from 1000 tokens per day to 500 tokens per day, after a user has staked for 1 day.

Can I do it via modifier?

The possible solution I found was [`ethereum-alarm-clock`](https://github.com/ethereum-alarm-clock/ethereum-alarm-clock) but couldn't manage to make it work. How can i use Ethereum-alarm-clock for this usecase?

Any other solutions are welcome too.

Comment: Do you deliver the staking reward each day to the user's address? Or does he have to get it all at once when he is unstaking his tokens?

Comment: Users can claim their rewards anytime they want. It is just a booster reward for a day. For example, for the first day of staking, users get 2X rewards, afterwards, 1X.

Comment: Save the timestamp when the stack begins, then get the timestamp when the user decided to claim its reward, then do the math. I would do something like this.